# I want to ask Specifically about the Microsoft V B A

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I created a user form which called "Product Master" that can help me to add a products and details about it in the workbook sheet, after it can automatically display those details in the user form list box as they appear in the Excel Sheet.
For Example:
This Image shows the sheet and the user form I created, can add product details but cannot display them in the list box.
[image: This Image shows the sheet and the user form I created, can add product details but cannot display them in the list box.]

This Image shows the code I used and are not working
[image: This Image shows the code I used and are not working]

```
    With Data_List_Box
        .RowSource = "sheet1!A:D"
        .ColumnCount = 4
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnWidths = "60,150,80,80"
        .RowSource = "Product_Master!A2:D"
        
        'shw data into the Data_List_Box
        ws.Cells(Column, 1).Value = S.No.Value 'Sirial_number
        ws.Cells(Column, 2).Value = Distributor_Price.Value 'Distributor_Price
        ws.Cells(Column, 3).Value = Retail_Price.Value 'Retail Price
    End With
End Sub
```

I tried to use the ways I specified above and Expecting to add product and its details so that automatically can display them in the list box.

Comment: `A2:D` is not a valid address in Excel.

Comment: Please, never post images of code (and tables). Nobody wants to spend time on rewriting code (or data) that simply could be copy-pasted for testing.

Comment: Please, [don't post a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table or use this [website](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to create a Markdown table.